# plotply scala sbt unresolved dependency not found

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, plotly

I am trying to get started with plotly using scala. I am following their [guide](https://plot.ly/scala/getting-started/) to the letter but sbt returns an error:

```
Error:Error while importing SBT project:
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#run;0.13.8 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#task-system;0.13.8 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#tasks;0.13.8 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#tracking;0.13.8 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#cache;0.13.8 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#testing;0.13.8 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#test-agent;0.13.8 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#test-interface;1.0 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#main-settings;0.13.8 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#apply-macro;0.13.8 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#command;0.13.8 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#logic;0.13.8 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#precompiled-2_8_2;0.13.8 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#precompiled-2_9_2;0.13.8 ...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt#precompiled-2_9_3;0.13.8 ...
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run 'last *:update' for the full output.
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run 'last *:ssExtractDependencies' for the full output.
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: co.theasi#plotly_2.11;0.2.0: not found
[error] (*:ssExtractDependencies) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: co.theasi#plotly_2.11;0.2.0: not found
[error] Total time: 10 s, completed Jul 16, 2016 3:29:59 PM</pre><br/>See complete log in <a href="/home/michael/.IdeaIC2016.1/system/log/sbt.last.log">/home/michael/.IdeaIC2016.1/system/log/sbt.last.log</a>
```

Can someone please help me resolve this issue?

My build.sbt is as follows:

```
name := "plotly"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies += "co.theasi" %% "plotly" % "0.2.0"
```

Comment: What's in the `build.sbt`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is only `0.1` version on maven central - [link](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/co.theasi/plotly_2.11/0.1). And 0.2 is not yet released. To use 0.2 version change your `build.sbt` file:

```
resolvers += "Sonatype OSS Snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"
libraryDependencies += "co.theasi" %% "plotly" % "0.2-SNAPSHOT"
```